# Get Files from another server (Error 500.19)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis-10

I've internal Asp.Net Core Site running on IIS10 in my company.
Now i thought its a good idea to access pdf files from another server via a virtual directory. (Maybe someone has another idea)

We have 1 Server with Active Directory User, the File Server and the Server where IIS is running.

I tried absolut everything with permissions, at the end nearly everything had Admin Access but IIS still keeps meaning it has not enough permissions.
(Maybe i missed a restart at some point, i dont know)
I read much about the iis_iusrs the active directory has no user only a group where i added the iis user.
Other way giving the folder *iisServer\iis_iusrs* permissions isnt accepted
I've this error:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-error-500-19-webpage

I read that its not the web.config but tried also many permission options.

At the end i'm pretty confused, didnt think that its so complicated or maybe i'm doing everything wrong

Maybe someone knows a way for dummys which always work.

Comment: "its a good idea to access pdf files from another server via a virtual directory". No. That can be a bad idea to increase unnecessary latency and bandwidth consumption. The actual 500.19 error can be caused by your application pool identity selection, which has not enough permissions to access the file share.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Application Pool User has more than enough permissions. What do think would be an alternative? Download the files in a temp folder and open?

Comment: Do you have detailed information about the 500.19 error? For example: HRESULT code. In the advanced settings of your website, Edit the setting of Physical Path Credentials and make sure that the Application User (pass-through authentication) is selected.

Comment: Samwu, thanks for your answer. I think the pass-through helped a bit, had a AD user selected. Now i run in a 404 error, when i add a web.config in the directory i get different errors (500.19) . But a web.config in the folder isnt required, or? Before pass through i had 0x80070005

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way to slove the question:

1. Open the Internet Information Services.
2. Expand the root node, expand Sites, and right-click on your Application, click Manage Web Site ->Advanced Settings.
3. Note down the Application Pool name under General settings and close the window.
4. Now go to Application Pools section, here you can see what Identity is used in the corresponding Application Pool.
5. Here, the user account `testuser1` is configured in Application Pool. So we need give required permissions for this user in the website directory.
6. Go the abother web directory folder, right-click on the folder and click Properties.
7. Set required permissions for the Identity(`testuser1`) that used in ApplicationPool.
8. Restart Application Pool and Web Application and try again.

Comment: Didnt work, sorry, still 404. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: Try to use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.